# Why are some System.Security.Cryptography classes only available in a .NET PCL when they are referenced via a seperate DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, portable-class-library

I have noticed some inconsistencies with several classes in the System.Security.Cryptography namespace. I am unable to use them directly in my PCL project 'X'. However, if I use the classes in one of my other PCL projects 'Y', then it works fine.

Even stranger, if I reference the DLL produced by 'Y' from 'X', I do not get any build/runtime issues when 'X' utilities 'Y'.

Example classes with this "problem":

- RNGCryptoServiceProvider
- HMACSHA256

In case it makes any difference to the answer, I am using Profile 78 and will be using the PCL projects in Xamarin projects.

I am wondering...

1. Why am I not able to use the classes directly (only via an external DLL)?
2. And more importantly, if I were to continue to utilise 'Y' from 'X', will this cause problems in the future e.g. not working on certain devices?

Comment: The usual reason, profile78 allows you to use your library on .NETCore targets that run on a phone or Linux or OSX.  Which don't have the FIPS certified cryptographic code, unmanaged DLLs that are only available on a Windows desktop machine.  Nothing to do with "not allowed", it just keeps you out of trouble.  The "works anyway" scenario is unclear, maybe you did not test your library on such targets.